Graph removal lemma for bipartite graph
Let $H$ be a bipartite graph with $h$ vertices. If we need to remove $\epsilon n^2$ edges from a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices to make it $H$-free, then $G$ contains at least $\epsilon^c n^h$ copies of $H$.
My attempts
I tried to prove it by adjusting the proof of the general graph removal lemma. However, the proof uses the graph counting lemma and the regularity lemma. Applying the regularity lemma brings an annoying constant, so we can only come up with $\delta n^h$ copies.
I also tried to prove it via the Kovari-Sos-Turan:
Suppose that $G$ has $\epsilon n^2$ edges. Let $M$ be the number of $K_{1,h}$ in $G$. For a subset of $S\subset V(G)$ of size $h$, let $f(S)$ be the number of vertices adjacent to all vertices in $S$. Then
$$\sum_{v\in V}\binom{d(v)}{h}=M=\sum_{S\in\binom{V}{h}}f(S).$$
Let $N$ be the number of copies of $K_{h,h}$ in $G$. Then
\begin{align*}
    N=&\frac{1}{2}\sum_{S\in \binom{V}{h}}\binom{f(S)}{h}\\
    \geq&\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{h}\binom{\sum f(S)\big/\binom{n}{h}}{h}\\
    =& \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{h}\binom{M\big/\binom{n}{h}}{h}\\
    =&\Omega (n^{h-h^2})M^h\\
    =&\Omega (n^{h-h^2})\left(\sum_{v\in V}\binom{d(v)}{h}\right)^h\\
    =&\Omega(n^{h-h^2})n^h\binom{2e(G)/n}{h}^h\\
    =&\Omega((2\epsilon)^{h^2}n^{2h}).
\end{align*}
Still cannot get rid of the constant.
